# Host PC fails to access Webmin which is installed on CentOS in VirtualBox

Tags: centos, networking, virtualbox, port-forwarding, webmin

Webmin can be accessed over SSH after forwarding the port.

Now I am trying to access Webmin's control panel on my computer outside virtualbox but on the same computer, but it doesn't load.

I tried using the same port forwarding settings as is working fine for SSH, for both port 80 and port 10000, but it still doesn't load. The browser error says,

```
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
```

Here's my network settings for port forwarding in virtualbox:

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install fresh CentOS 7 x64 (latest)
2. Install Webmin
3. `yum update -y`
4. Add Port Forwarding rule for 2222 to 22 to make SSH work
5. No iptables are installed. Just vanilla CentOS 7 x64 latest with Webmin latest freshly installed.
6. Open browser on computer (the same computer running VirtualBox & SSH but outside VirtualBox), and go to `http://127.0.0.1:10000`

It fails to connect.

[image]

This is what I want to see (pulled screenshot from the internet):
[image]

I also tried accessing from 192.168.x.x (my PC's IP), but I get connection refused:

[image]

I tried forwarding port 10000 to my local pc's IP port 10000 too, but still doesn't work:

[image]

I can't use bridged because port forwarding is greyed out.

[image]

I did try setting up a bridged connection, but then even SSH wouldn't connect, as well as either my host PC's IP (`http://192.168.x.x:10000`) or (`http://127.0.0.1:10000`)

To troubleshoot I ran nmap in SSH:

```
# nmap 192.168.x.x -p 10000 -sU -sT -Pn --reason

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2022-06-14 21:33 EDT
Nmap scan report for DESKTOP-CHTUIRP (192.168.x.x)
Host is up, received user-set (0.0013s latency).
PORT      STATE    SERVICE          REASON
10000/tcp filtered snet-sensor-mgmt no-response
10000/udp filtered ndmp             port-unreach from 10.x.x.x

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.47 seconds
```

Then I tried from localhost, but localhost (127.0.0.1) seems to be up.

```
# nmap 127.0.0.1 -p 10000 -sU -sT -Pn --reason

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2022-06-14 21:35 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up, received user-set (0.021s latency).
PORT      STATE SERVICE          REASON
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt syn-ack
10000/udp open  ndmp             udp-response

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.98 seconds
```

also seems to be up from the guest IP (10.x.x.x)

```
# nmap 10.x.x.x -p 10000 -sU -sT -Pn --reason

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2022-06-14 21:41 EDT
Nmap scan report for 10.x.x.x
Host is up, received user-set (0.00021s latency).
PORT      STATE SERVICE          REASON
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt syn-ack
10000/udp open  ndmp             udp-response

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.79 seconds
```

How to connect and log into WebMin that is installed in VirtualBox, in a browser on the host PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: SOLVED IT!! I'm leaving this data here, like my other questions, to hopefully help others.

The problem was threefold.

1. **Firewall**: I DID have a firewall installed. `firewall-cmd --state` and it returned `running`.

> To debug, I stopped the firewall with `systemctl stop firewalld` (it hung, but I
> pressed CTRL+C to terminate the command) then ran `firewall-cmd --state` and it returned `not running`.

> But now make sure to re-enable firewall if you haven't:

```
systemctl start firewalld
```

> Now you don't want to leave your firewall running. So since I know what firewall I have, now I can open the port 10000:

```
`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=10000/tcp`
```

> With that command run, now you will be able to access port 10000.

2. **Port forwarding**: I had also updated the port forwarding in VirtualBox to this:

> [image]
>
> Yes, I chose `127.0.0.5`, but it should probably work now anyway if I
> used `127.0.0.1` too, I just used `.5` which is one of the localhost
> numbers to help narrow down the problem)

3. **Hostname problem**: After that, http://127.0.0.5:10000 gave this error:

> [image]
>
> So I clicked that link, and didn't load, but that's because I never set up a hostname (that's the default on CentOS install if you don't change it).
>
> Change hostname with this:

```
hostname 127.0.0.1
```

> Yes I set hostname to the IP since I didn't have any domains on it of course.
>
> Then after that I went to the https version:

```
https://127.0.0.5:10000
```

> (because I had port forwarded `127.0.0.5` in VirtualBox settings pictured above)

And after passing the SSL error, it loaded up WebMin!

[image]

Success!!